# How to make 'None selected' not to work on change of drop down

Tags: javascript, html

NameTextBox is Dropdown with all names so once change of names and click on search then it gets details associated to the Name but by default 'None Selected' is displayed so once click on search this also works. How can i restrict 'None Selected' not to work once i click on search.

```
<select id="NameTextBox" name="NameTextBox" class="select100" onchange="fnChangeName();">
                                    <option value=""><fmt:message key="label.select"/></option>
                                    <c:forEach var="item" items="${MODEANDVIEW.model.codes}">
                                        <c:set var="numb_Code" value='=${item.numb}'/>
                                        <%
                                        String numbCode = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("numb_Code");
                                        String LoopVal=numbCode.replaceAll(" ","");                                         
                                        String compare = numb.replaceAll(" ","");
                                        selected="";                                            
                                        if((LoopVal.substring(1)).equalsIgnoreCase(compare)){
                                            selected="selected";
                                        }


function fnChangeName(){

document.<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()%>emitform.addr.value=document.<%=    
renderResponse.getNamespace()%>emitform.NameTextBox.options[document.<%= 
renderResponse.getNamespace()%>remitform.NameTextBox.selectedIndex].value +   
"\n";
var str=document.<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()%>emitform.addr.value;
var str2=document.<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()%>emitform.addr.value;
var str3=str.substring(0,str.indexOf(":"));
document.<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()%>emitform.addr1.value=str3;
document.<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()%>emitform.pvId.value=str3;
}
```

Comment: I've deleted your [tag:java] tag as your question doesn't appear to have much to do with use of this language. Please understand that Java ans Javascript are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : yeah sure, you are exact. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and easy approach - On button click, inside function fnChangeName, Just check that if 'None Selected' is slected then return false or write "return;". This will definitely work.

To get the selected value in the name drop down,  you can use options attribute of your drop down.

in javascript:

```
function fnChangeName(){

   var txtName = document.getElementById("NameTextBox");
   var selectedName = txtName .options[txtName.selectedIndex].text;
   if(selectedName == "None Selected")
     return;

   document.<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()%>emitform.addr.value=document.<%=    
   renderResponse.getNamespace()%>emitform.NameTextBox.options[document.<%= 
   renderResponse.getNamespace()%>remitform.NameTextBox.selectedIndex].value +   
   "\n";
   var str=document.<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()%>emitform.addr.value;
   var str2=document.<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()%>emitform.addr.value;
   var str3=str.substring(0,str.indexOf(":"));
   document.<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()%>emitform.addr1.value=str3;
   document.<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()%>emitform.pvId.value=str3;
}
```

Comment: Tons of Thanks! It worked great. I don't have the reputation to vote up :-)